# how to optimize this function?

Tags: java, optimization

How to optimize this function as much as possible

```
public void r1(String st1, int[] ar1) {
    String inox = "newsearch";
    for (int j = 0; j < ar1.length; j++) {
        if (st1.equals(inox) && ar1[j] * 2 > 20) {
            Integer intx = new Integer(ar1[j]);
            intx = intx * 2;
            System.out.print(intx.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have optimised the presentation for you - anything else you need? (ps: you can use int instead of Integer - that should speed up things a bit)

Comment: What do you want to optimize? If you are least bothered about explaining what it does why should one bother to analyse and answer it?

Comment: I don't see any obvious optimization. Why do you want to do it? Is it slow?

Answer (score 6):

This is rather odd code but its the same as.

```
public void r1(String st1, int[] ar1) {
    if (!str1.equals("newsearch")) return;

    for (int j : ar1) {
        int j2 = j * 2;
        if (j2 > 20) 
            System.out.print(j2);
    }
}
```

Comment: replacing str1.equals("newsearch") with "newsearch".equals(str1) helps avoid NullPointerException

Comment: True, but that could have been intended. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void r1(String st1, int[] ar1) {
    String inox = "newsearch";
    if (st1.equals(inox) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ar1.length; j++) {
             if (ar1[j] > 10) {
                System.out.print(ar1[j] * 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not doing the same thing.

Comment: BTW: `(1 << 30) * 2 < 0` but `(1 << 30) > 0`

Comment: but in this case I think we can simplify

Answer (score 0):

```
public void r1(String st1, int[] ar1) {
  if (st1.equals("newsearch") {
    for (int j = 0; j < ar1.length; j++) {
      if (ar1[j] > 10) {
        System.out.print(ar1[j] * 2);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of Peter Lawreys version:

```
public void r1(String st1, int[] ar1) {
    if (!str1.equals("newsearch"))
        return;
    for (int j : ar1)
        if (j > 10)
            System.out.print(j << 1);
}
```